# Can't run tests after upgrading to react-native 0.56

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I recently updated react-native to 0.56. I am aware of the significant updates to Babel 7 and have tried everything listed here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19859 but I am still unable to get my tests running properly. Adding the following line to my package.json has helped alot.

```jsx
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
},
```

My problem now is that I am unable to test stateless components. I get Component not found. Below are my dependencies:

```jsx
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.1.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^5.13.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.61.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native-webpack-server": "^0.9.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.0"
  },
```

Here is an example of a component that throws this error and the following Spec:

Component:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import styles from '../../styles/components/common/spinner'

const Spinner = ({ size, spinnerStyle, color }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.spinnerStyle, spinnerStyle]}>
      <ActivityIndicator color={color} size={size || 'large'} animating={true} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default Spinner
```

Test:

```jsx
import { View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Spinner from '../Spinner'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Spinner', () => {
  var component

  beforeAll(() => {
    component = shallow(<Spinner size={'small'} />)
  })

  it('has the View wrapper', () => {
    expect(component).toHaveChild(View)
  })

  it('has the ActivityIndicator', () => {
    expect(component).toHaveChild('ActivityIndicator')
  })
})
```

When I add console.log(component.debug()) to the test I get the following output so I can see that the component isn't being rendered as expected.

```jsx
<Component style={{...}}>
  <Component color={[undefined]} size="small" animating={true} />
</Component>
```

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me downgrading this `"babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.1"` -->  `"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0"` got rid of that error.

Be sure to remove your node_modules folder and run `npm/yarn install`.